# Exclude some characters in string

Tags: javascript, regex

In quotes I try to exclude the `;` characters using regex in Node.js.

For example i have an sql like below:

```
update codes set character='.' where character = ';' and write_date < now()-5 ;
```

I want to find effected rows before execute the statement. I wrote below regex but it not work correctly if there is `;` character in quotes as above

```js
const regexp = /update\s+((.|\n)[^;]*?)\s+set\s+((.|\n)[^;]*?)\s+where\s+((.|\n)[^;]*?);/ig;
regexp.exec(str)
```

Expected output:

```
table: codes
where: character = ';' and write_date < now()-5
```

But I get:

```
table: codes
where: character = ';
```

Comment: `.*;.*` will match all of a string containing `;`

Comment: Maybe `update\s+([^;]*?)\s+set\s(?:[^;]*?\s)?where\s+((?:'[^']*'|[^;])*?)\s*;` will do. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fkLGEQ/1).

Comment: Is the OP looking for [something like the following linked example](https://regex101.com/r/ZU02hp/1)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
update\s+([^;]*?)\s+set\s(?:[^;]*?\s)?where\s+((?:'[^']*'|[^;])*?)\s*;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fkLGEQ/1). *Details*:

- `update` - a word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([^;]*?)` - Group 1: zero or more but as few as possible chars other than `;`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `set` - a word
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?:[^;]*?\s)?` - an optional sequence of any chars other than `;` as few as possible, and then a whitespace
- `where` - a word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `((?:'[^']*'|[^;])*?)` - Group 2: zero or more (as few as possible) sequences of `'`, zero or more non-`'`s, and then `'`, or any single char other than a `;`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `;` - a `;` char.

Answer (score 0):

First of, I'm not sure what `(.|\n)` is for, so I'm ignoring that.

I believe there are two problems with your regexp, changing either will probably solve your problem, but I'd change both, just to be sure.

1. The `?` after the `*` makes the `*` non-greedy, which means the regex will match as little as possible, so that the final `;` in the regexp will match the first possible `;` it finds, not the last possible. So I'd leave the `?` out.
2. The regexp doesn't use `$` to anchor to the end of string. Add `$` after `;` at the end (possibly `\s*$` if you expect additional white space at the end of the string). If you do this, you actually don't need to exclude `;`. And it may be a good idea, to add `^` (or `^\s*`) at the beginning to anchor to the beginning of the string, too.

So the resulting regexp is

```
const regexp = /^\s*update\s+((.|\n).*)\s+set\s+((.|\n).*)\s+where\s+((.|\n).*);\s*$/ig;
```

Finally some conceptional ideas: Why are you doing this in the first place? Instead of starting with the UPDATE SQL, why don't you start out with the structure:

```
{ 
  table: "codes",
  where: "character = ';' and write_date < now()-5"
}
```

and build both the UPDATE and the SELECT SQLs from that?

Or if you only have the UPDATE SQL, instead of using a regular expression, there are SQL parser libraries ([example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sql-parser)) which would probably be more reliable.